# Young adult/children's book about space and plague

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, young-adult

Read this book about 9-10 years ago as a kid, it was centred mostly aboard a space ship where there was a deadly plague and the astronauts were racing against time to shut down all systems. If I recall correctly there was a couple who were separated, one aboard the ship and the other one on earth, and the astronauts decided to sacrifice themselves by locking themselves in capsules and go down with the ship. My memory is failing as it was so long ago, so the story might not be exactly as I think it was.

I recall that the book cover was grey.